# How can I add more space for indicators?

Tags: indicator, panel

I am running 12.04 LTS and have used My Unity to set the Launcher as needed, and even added Classic Menu Indicator to the top bar to the far right, next to the default icons.

I found Classic Menu Indicator here:  http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/

*My question is, with that very same small amount of icon space available at the top right, how do I add more items?*

I understand the rest of the top bar from middle to far left is used by the active app.  *is there a way to tweak the space it takes to open more room for custom items?*

I use these systems as hardcore work machines to every centimeter of user space is worth pursuing.

Answer (score 0):

The area will autoadjust in size based on the amount of indicators you have loaded, so the more you add it will just grow.

See this list for a list of available indicators:

- [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available)